# 301 Redirects From Old WordPress Site to New WordPress Site with URL Structure Changes

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I just uploaded a redesigned and developed WP website and I was wondering how I would go about updating the old URL's with the new ones automatically. I am not sure if this has to be a manual process as I am still fairly new to WP. Below is an example of my URL structure:

Old Site:

```
http://example.com/service-page-here/
```

New Site:

```
http://example.com/services/service-page-here/
```

Answer (score 1):

From your example, it would seem that all page URLs have simply moved into a `/services` "subdirectory"? In which case, you could do something like the following *before* the existing WordPress directives (front controller):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/services/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/)?$ /services/$1 [R=302,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* only matches single path segments containing the characters `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z`, `_` and `-` (hyphen).

The first `RewriteCond` directive that checks against `REQUEST_URI` ensures we don't redirect URLs that have already been redirected. And the other `RewriteCond` directives (like the WordPress conditions) ensure we don't redirect URLs that otherwise map directly to files or directories.

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to `301` (permanent) only when you are sure it's working OK.

Comment: Thank you so much!